# Placeholder value for textarea in Ext.Msg

Tags: extjs

I'm new to ExtJS. It seems I am unable to find in documentation the option to set the placeholder value for the textarea that appears inside `Ext.Msg`.

This is my code so far:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
                title: 'Approve Confirmation',
                message: 'Confirm to approve the selected items?',
                multiline: 'true',
                iconCls: 'fa fa-check-square-o',
                buttonText: {
                    ok: 'Yes',
                    cancel: 'No'
                },
                height:350,
                width:500,
                defaultTextHeight:210,
                closable: false
                fn: function(btn,text){
                    //some HTTP process
                }
            });
```

How do I display placeholder text inside the textarea?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prompt` property. Read this [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.MessageBox.html#cfg-prompt)

```
title: 'Approve Confirmation',
message: 'Confirm to approve the selected items?',
multiline: 'true',
prompt: { 
     placeholder: "type whatever you want",
     maxlength: 200, 
     autocapitalize: false,
     //other properties...
}
```

Comment: The placeholder text does not show up. Do I need to move everything after multiline into the prompt object?

Comment: What version of extJS are you using?

Comment: 6.0.1, I discovered through trial and error that prompt doesn’t seem to work for that version. I tested it out on the ExtJS sandbox using 6.0.1 Classic.

Comment: It's alright. Turns out you can just set the placeholder like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789677/placeholder-text-for-messagebox/65794626#65794626